# Background process in linux using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, fedora, background-process

I want to do some  process such as sending emails or using ffmpeg commands in backgound as it takes to much time. I want it should run in a background. I am using Fedora 10. Also can i check whether my background process is running successfully or not . is it posssible?if yes what would be the steps i should follow.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Delayed Job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [BackgrounDRb](http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/)